# How can I import a module's Typescript types for use in my own type definitions?

Tags: typescript, import

I would like to write a type for an options object, which itself includes a type from an imported module, in this case Moment.js:

```
import moment from 'moment'

export type myOptions = {
 // ...
 myDate: Moment;
}

export function myFunction(options: myOptions) {
 // ...
}
```

This doesn't work, it seems that the type 'Moment' is not imported with the library 'moment':

```
$ npx tsc
example.ts:5:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Moment'.

5  myDate: Moment;
           ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Is there a way to build on types from other libraries this way?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, okay, this type actually is available on the moment default export:

```
import moment from 'moment'

export type myOptions = {
  myDate: moment.Moment;
}
```

I don't know how one can discover this sort of thing without reading the source on every library you want to use, though.